# Image Size should not vary based on distance between Android phone and Image while using Camera

Tags: android, camera, android-imageview

I wanna implement this Programatically. While taking Image in android phone,image size should not vary based on distance between Android Phone and Actual Image,

for example,If distance between Android Phone and View is more ,then taken Image will look Big,If distance is less,then image will look small.

Is there any way to implement this?

Reference : I'm using https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper lib for taking and Cropping  Image from android phone.

In this Project, file name : CropResultActivity,I have coded from Line number 50 to 65

Here **mImage** is Bitmap of Cropped Image.(Please refer git-hub project for more Info)

```
if (mImage != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mImage);
            int sampleSize = intent.getIntExtra("SAMPLE_SIZE", 1);
            double ratio = ((int) (10 * mImage.getWidth() / (double) mImage.getHeight())) / 10d;
            int byteCount = 0;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                byteCount = mImage.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( mImage.getWidth(), mImage.getHeight());
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

            String desc = "(" + mImage.getWidth() + ", " + mImage.getHeight() +
                    "), Sample: " + sampleSize + ", Ratio: " + ratio + ", Bytes: " + byteCount + "K";
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultImageText)).setText(desc);
        }
```

Comment: Well thats how it works actually. You do not have to do anything for that. Build in!

Comment: How to confirm this.actually I have taken two pics ,One is near and another is far.From Bitmap's getHeight() and getWidth() I have calculated height and width,I got different values.Let me know what ever i have followed is correct

Comment: Bitmap's getHeight() and getWidth() returns Pixel of Image?

Comment: Show your calculations.

Comment: After Taking Image,I given option to Crop that ,then  I'm Calculating Height and Width from Bitmap of Cropped Image,First I kept more distance between my Android phone and real picture ,that time i got width and height as 441, 281,Next for less distance i got width and height as 1342, 798.If i calculate image height and width in Inches I should get Same from Both measurement,Is it possible?.I consider 441,281 unit as dp ,I used http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/ link for converting dp to Inches.

Comment: Please put all info and code in your post. Mske a decent story. Nobody knows where you are talking about. Complete code please.

Comment: @greenapps, added more code.Please check

Comment: `While taking Image in android phone,image size should not vary based on distance between Android Phone and Actual Image,` Well whatever you consider to be 'image size' i don't know. The camera takes a picture with a certain resolution. This resolution is always the same. So please explain first what influce distance would have on resolution according to you. Or on what else exactly. Further i do not understand why you start talking about cropping. You did not tell why you would crop. I do understand nothing of what you described. Please try to write a post that can be understood by everyone.

Comment: okay, Forget about cropping now,Just consider I am taking Same picture from Android Camera two times,One is from Long distance and another is from short distance.How android Calculates Height and Width from Bitmap?

Comment: Huhhh. Why would Android go and calculate something? Android? The Camera app took two pictures is it? And saved them? Correct? Then confirm! After that... why would Android calculate something? The .jpg files produced by the camera app will have the same resolution. So same widthxheight. There is no Bitmap! There are only two .jpg files. Now from here on tell exactly what you want and do. IN YOUR POST.

Comment: Now Just consider both images are Same.But one is taken from short and another is from long distance.I will crop same place/position in both the images.will i get Same height and width from Bitmap of cropped image.

Comment: In is unclear when you consider images to be the same. It is unclear what you want to crop. Post your code. I will not look into the links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135748/discussion-between-dya-and-greenapps).